# MVC API route not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need a second set of eyes on this please.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I had my routing api working at one point now it won't behave at all.  I just get 404 errors or 405 errors.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}


[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody]Preregistration prereg, string password, string passwordConfirm)
{
    // guts
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new[] { "ok" });
}
```

If I remove all the parameters of my put method it works and I get a response, but when I add them back it fails.

Below is what I'm sending to the server in the http body:

```
prereg[firstName]           test
prereg[lastName]            test
prereg[email]               test@test.org
prereg[emailConfirm]        test@test.org
prereg[isCellPhone]         false
prereg[captcha]             false
prereg[isValid]             true
prereg[isAnyMessageShown]   false
prereg[moveDate]            11/30/2013
password                    Password1
passwordConfirm             Password1
```

Comment: If you start with one parameter? Does it work then?

Comment: No, even one paramater blows it up.

Comment: Why is it a `Put` not a `Post`? What happens if you have one parameter and add it to the querystring for a post like `www.domain.com/api/controller?password=test`? Are you using fiddler to post?

Comment: Nope, post doesn't work either.

Comment: I believe if you specify the `[FromBody]` attribute, you can only have that one parameter. To test this, can you please try removing `password` and `passwordConfirm` parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to move the `password` to an object along with the other properties, this would work:

**The User Model:**

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string EmailConfirm { get; set; }
    public bool IsCellPhone { get; set; }
    public bool Captcha { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnyMessageShow { get; set; }
    public DateTime MoveDate { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }


}
```

**The controller:**

```
 public void Put(User user)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
```

**The call in fiddler (json):**

A `PUT` to `http://localhost:1099/api/values` (on my machine) with these headers:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:1099
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

And this body:

{"FirstName" : "first", "LastName":"Test", "Email": "test@test.org", "EmailConfirm": "test@test.org", "IsCellPhone": "false","Captcha": "false", "IsValid": "true", "IsAnyMessageShown": "false", "MoveDate": "2013-01-01", "Password": "Password1",  "PasswordConfirm": "Password1"}

**The result in a breakpoint in Visual Studio:**

[image: Json Api call example]

Comment: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried putting `[FromBody]` attribute on `password` and `passwordConfirm` ? Those parameters won't be set because string or int (or any other value type) are fetch from the querystring, not the body of your request.